# Editable widget and grouping widget are incompatible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm trying to edit childRow cell data using the editable and grouping widgets.

After editing a cell's data that resides in a child row, tablesorter puts this message in the console: **"Tablesorter Warning! "updateCell" for child row content has been disabled, use "update" instead."** The edit to the child row data fails/returns even before the editComplete event is fired.

Does this mean that the grouping widget and the editable widget are incompatible, at least with respect to editing child rows? (Parent row data edits do work, it should be noted.)  Is there a clean workaround for editing child row data?

Comment: The editable widget uses "updateCell" to update the cache. If the child row doesn't have content that needs to be filtered, then you can ignore this warning. If it does need to be searchable, then we'll need to find an alternative.

Comment: @Mottie - Thanks for the reply.  Ultimately, I followed the warning's advice and modified the editable widget's call to updateCell to instead call the update method.  This seems to have resolved the issue with no noticeable side-affects. Am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, but if you have a large table, the update method is slower since it is parsing all the table cells instead of just one.